# Cast function returning year and month only

Tags: mysql

```
select invoice_date, cast(invoice_date as date) as new_date from invoices limit 5;
```

I need to return only the month and year..any help?
I have to use the cast function

Comment: Why do you have to use the cast function?

Comment: That's what the instructions are

Comment: Write a SELECT statement that returns these columns from the Invoices table:
• The invoice_date column
• A column that uses the CAST function to return the invoice_date column with just the year and month, calling it new_date

Comment: Those are silly requirements. Is this homework? Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: No, im asking for help? I got most of the code?

Comment: What's the column type of invoice_date?

Comment: the column type is 'date'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the DATE_FORMAT to only show the month and year.

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(CAST(invoice_date as DATE), '%m/%Y') as new_date from invoices
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MONTH() and YEAR() functions on the date type.

If you must use CAST(), then I guess you could cast to a string type and get a substring.

Answer (score 2):

```
cast(invoice_date as char(7)) AS new_date
```

would give you 1999-10 for example.

I'm doing my homework with a similar question lol.